# Проблема с unset(), php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть у меня 2 массива. Первый - комплексы, второй - объекты этих комплексов. Для того чтобы вывести их сгрупированнимы использую такую схему.

```
foreach ($complex as $com) { //запускаем цикл по комплексам
  echo '<h2 align="center">Complex: ' . $com['name'] . '</h2>'; // выводим название комплекса
  for ($i = 0; $i <= count($object) - 1; $i++) { // запускаем цикл по обьектам
    echo 'Прохожение массив' . $i . ' ';
    if ($com['id'] == $object[$i]['complex_id']) { //проверка, на то, обьект етого комплекса или нет
      echo 'Object: ' . $object[$i]['name'] . '<br>'; // если да то выводим
      //unset($object[$i]);
      //sort($object);
    }
  }
}
```

Работает нормально, но проблема в том, что по такой схеме очень много данных проходит через цикл `for`. Получается что сколько обьектов - столько раз будет пройден цикл `for` у каждого комплекса отдельно.

Решил попробовать использовать функцию `unset();`. Если в цикле `for` проверка на обьект этого комплекса проходит, т.е. выводится название объекта -  `echo 'Object: ' . $object[$i]['name']` . Тогда применять `unset();`

```
if ($com['id'] == $object[$i]['complex_id']) { 
  echo 'Object: ' . $object[$i]['name'] . '<br>'; 
  unset($object[$i]);
  sort($object);
}
```

Но проблема в том, что не корректно работает. Если есть только 1 объект в комплексе - работает ОК, если 2 объекта - тогда показывает только 1 объект, если 3 объекта - тогда показывает 2 , но если 4 объекта - всеравно показывает 2 объекта, и так далее.. НЕ могу понять почему?

Результат прохождения по циклу без UNSET

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь с UNSET, почему так - незнаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией и страдаете от этого.

Comment: Та не думаю, дай на вход массива даже 1000 объектов - уже будет заметно увеличения время загрузки страницы

Answer (score 1):

[Sort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sort.php) изменяет очерёдность элементов, при том что перебор идёт по числовому ключу. 
Используйте внутренний указатель массива и уберите `sort`.

```
for ($value = reset($object); $value !== false; $value = next($object)) {
    $key = key($object);
    # do something whith $value;
}
```

---

NOTE

На будущее - `foreach` работает с копией массива, в нём исходный массив во время итерации менять бессмысленно.

Comment: Получается я не меняю главный массив foreach, а внутри foreach другой массив меняю - foreach это complex, а for это object. Если я перепишу for как у Вас, тогда как обращаться через ключ? `$object[$i]['complex_id']`  было, если делаю вот так  `$object[item]['complex_id']` - пишет что Illegal offset type

Comment: Заметка о `foreach` гласит, что им проблему не решить.


Для получения ключа есть функция [key](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.key.php)

Comment: @VladShkuta, как успехи?

Comment: отписал в комент

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, как у Вас, unset не работает - все равно не меняется количество "заходов" в массив - echo 'Зашел в массив'.'
';

```
for ($value = reset($object); $value !== false; $value = next($object)) {
                           $key = key($object);
                           echo 'Зашел в массив'.'<br>';
                            if ($com['id'] == $value['complex_id']) {
                                echo 'Object: ' . $value['name'] . '<br>'; // если да то выводим
                                unset($value);

                            }
                  }
```

Comment: `unset($object[$key])` - удалять `$value` бессмысленно. Здесь только предлагают решение, код пишите Вы сами